# How to connect a 2 wire current sensor to a 3-wire set-up?

Tags: analog, sensor, current-measurement, wire

At the moment I have a couple of 3 wire current(4-20mA) sensors inside my setup that have the same connection as the schematic below.

[image]

One of the sensors has broken. We can not directly get the same sensor again so we are looking at a new 2 wire current sensor that has the schematic as below.

[image: 2 wire current sensor]

Is there a way to connect the 2-wire sensor to the 3-wire setup without changing anything in the controller programming?

Comment: It looks to me your ADC part of the circuit is identical, output current with Rload to GND fed to ADC. I don't see any difference in behavior. So the circuit from pic.2 should work, if you find an actual part that functions the way you show it. Looks like some kind of LM334 constant current source circuit to me. If you already have a solution, what exactly is your question?

Comment: The second schematic is how you wire a two wire device. Where do you think there is a problem?

Comment: Apparently there is no problem in connecting the 2-wire transmitter. The ground does not need to be connected. The 2-wire transmitter is loop-powered so you don't need to provide it with an external power supply.

Comment: For clarification, I want to connect the 2-wire encoder from the bottom image to the schematic of the 3-wire encoder.

Comment: I Feel you all say "yes this will be possible without changing any settings inside my controller"

Answer (score 1):

This is fine as-is. The only possible issue is if the max input voltage of the controller plus the minimum voltage on the 2-wire transmitter added up to more than 24V, which is extremely unlikely. Usually a transmitter needs no more than 10V and the input no more than 5 or 10 at the most.

The two-wire transmitter will have a specification for maximum load resistance with a 24V supply or something of that ilk and you can double check but I'll wager there is zero issue.

Comment: I'll try this out. Will come back to this in a couple of weeks.